# Modify regex used to validate URL to allow IP addresses

Tags: javascript, regex

A developer that did work for me wrote a Regular expression that checks for valid urls when a user enters an url. It is working really well so far, except for the fact that it doesn't recognise IP addresses.

```
url = url.match(/(http\:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\S*)?/)
```

Correct:

```
Given: http://www.mywebsite.com/index.cfm?do=something
Result: http://www.mywebsite.com/index.cfm?do=something
```

Incorrect:

```
Given: http://64.200.10.50/index.cfm?do=something
Result: http://index.cfm?do=something

Should be: http://64.200.10.50/index.cfm?do=something
```

How would I modify the regex to account for IP addresses as well?

Thanks

Comment: easy solution: just allow everything except / and whitespaces between https:// and the first /. That way you will also support single level domain names, ipv6 addresses, etc

Comment: The regex will not match TLD like info, museum ...

Comment: @M42: I tested TLD and they work according to the solution offered below by arnaud. - Thanks for the heasd up though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

easy solution: just allow everything except / and whitespaces between https:// and the first /. That way you will also support single level domain names, ipv6 addresses, etc

```
/^https?\:\/\/[^\/\s]+(\/.*)?$/
```

Comment: Thanks - however your regex offered does not work correctly as far as I can see. The result is "http://64.200.10.50/" which is only part of the result if you look at the desired result I posted above.

Comment: Still not quite right. It is repeating part of the url now. For example, the url "http://fhg.met-art.com/2012-02-29/ESFINX/?pa=2163943" becomes "http://fhg.met-art.com/2012-02-29/ESFINX/?pa=2163943,/2012-02-29/ESFINX/?pa=2163943" Note the comma and repeating text.

Comment: how can a regex repeats its input ?

Comment: I don't know. I alert the url, apply the regex and alert it again and that's what displays: `alert(url);
      url = url.match(/^https?\:\/\/[^\/\s]+(\/.*)?$/)
      alert(url);`

Comment: ho I see; `.match()` returns an array. alert() converts the array to a string. Converting an array to a string usually concatenates all elements. Try `url=url.match(...); alert(url ? url[0] : false);`